Not able to share react-konva data between clients through websockets correctly
I am making a nextjs whiteboard application something like excalidraw, link here -https://excalidraw.com/
But in my case I am trying to make it real time collaborative where one person can enter the room Id of other person and they can then share the same whiteboard. I have built the logic to accommodate just two person for now. The problem I am facing is that when two persons are connected or in the same room, when I open another client in new tab, the two person that were connected get disconnected and can no longer share content. Here is my page.tsx file -
// components/Whiteboard.js
"use client";
import { KonvaEventObject } from "konva/lib/Node";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  Stage,
  Layer,
  Line,
  Circle,
  Rect,
  Arrow,
  Text,
  Transformer,
} from "react-konva";
import {
  MoveRight,
  Circle as IconCircle,
  RectangleHorizontal,
  PenLine,
  SquareMousePointer,
  RemoveFormatting,
} from "lucide-react";

const Whiteboard = () => {
  const [isDraggable, setIsDraggable] = useState(false);
  const [cliendId, setClientId] = useState("");
  const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState("");
  const [tool, setTool] = useState("arrow");
  const [lines, setLines] = useState<number[][]>([]);
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState<{ text: string; pos: number[] }[]>([
    { text: "", pos: [0, 0] },
  ]);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [arrows, setArrows] = useState<{ points: number[] }[]>([]);
  const [circles, setCircles] = useState<
    {
      x: number | undefined;
      y: number | undefined;
      radius: number;
      stroke: string;
      strokeWidth: number;
      isDragging: boolean;
    }[]
  >([{ x: 0, y: 0, radius: 0, stroke: "", strokeWidth: 0, isDragging: false }]);
  const [rectangles, setRectangles] = useState<
    {
      x: number | undefined;
      y: number | undefined;
      width: number;
      height: number;
      stroke: string;
      strokeWidth: number;
    }[]
  >([
    {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      stroke: "",
      strokeWidth: 0,
    },
  ]);
  const transformRef = useRef<any>();
  const isDrawing = useRef(false);
  const lastArrow = useRef<{
    points: number[];
  }>({
    points: [],
  });
  const lastLine = useRef<number[]>([]);
  const lastCircle = useRef<{
    x: number | undefined;
    y: number | undefined;
    radius: number;
    stroke: string;
    strokeWidth: number;
    isDragging: boolean;
  }>({
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined,
    radius: 0,
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    isDragging: false,
  });
  const lastRectangle = useRef<{
    x: number | undefined;
    y: number | undefined;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    stroke: string;
    strokeWidth: number;
  }>({
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 0,
  });
  const [ws, setWs] = useState<WebSocket | null>();

  const handleMouseDown = (event: KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) => {
    isDraggable === true
      ? (isDrawing.current = false)
      : (isDrawing.current = true);
    const pos = event.target.getStage()?.getPointerPosition();
    if (!pos) return;
    if (tool === "pen") {
      lastLine.current = [pos.x, pos.y];
    } else if (tool === "circle") {
      lastCircle.current = {
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y,
        radius: 0,
        stroke: "#000",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        isDragging: false,
      };
    } else if (tool === "rectangle") {
      lastRectangle.current = {
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        stroke: "#000",
        strokeWidth: 2,
      };
    } else if (tool === "arrow") {
      lastArrow.current = {
        points: [pos.x, pos.y],
      };
    }
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (event: KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) => {
    if (!isDrawing.current) return;
    const pos = event.target.getStage()?.getPointerPosition();
    if (!pos) return;
    if (tool === "pen") {
      let newLine =
        pos?.x !== undefined && pos?.y !== undefined
          ? lastLine.current.concat([pos.x, pos.y])
          : [...lastLine.current];
      setLines([...lines, newLine]);
      lastLine.current = [pos.x, pos.y];
      ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ lines }));
    } else if (tool === "circle") {
      if (!lastCircle.current.x || !lastCircle.current.y) return;
      let newRadius =
        Math.abs(pos.x - lastCircle.current.x) +
        Math.abs(pos.y - lastCircle.current.y);
      lastCircle.current.radius = newRadius;
      setCircles([...circles, lastCircle.current]);
      ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ circles }));
    } else if (tool === "rectangle") {
      if (!lastRectangle.current.x || !lastRectangle.current.y) return;
      let newWidth = Math.abs(pos.x - lastRectangle.current.x);
      let newHeight = Math.abs(pos.y - lastRectangle.current.y);
      lastRectangle.current.width = newWidth;
      lastRectangle.current.height = newHeight;
      setRectangles([...rectangles, lastRectangle.current]);
      ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ rectangles }));
    } else if (tool === "arrow") {
      const startPoint = [
        lastArrow.current.points[0],
        lastArrow.current.points[1],
      ];
      const endPoint = [pos.x, pos.y];
      const dx = endPoint[0] - startPoint[0];
      const dy = endPoint[1] - startPoint[1];
      const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      const arrowLength = 20;
      const arrowheadAngle = Math.PI / 6; // 30 degrees

      // Calculate arrowhead points
      const arrowheadPoint1 = [
        endPoint[0] - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle - arrowheadAngle),
        endPoint[1] - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle - arrowheadAngle),
      ];
      const arrowheadPoint2 = [
        endPoint[0] - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle + arrowheadAngle),
        endPoint[1] - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle + arrowheadAngle),
      ];

      lastArrow.current.points = [
        ...startPoint,
        ...endPoint,
        ...arrowheadPoint1,
        ...endPoint,
        ...arrowheadPoint2,
      ];
      setArrows([...arrows, lastArrow.current]);
      ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ arrows }));
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    isDrawing.current = false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.key === "s") {
        setIsDraggable(true);
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.key === "1") {
        setTool("text");
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.key === "2") {
        setTool("pen");
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.key === "3") {
        setTool("circle");
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.key === "4") {
        setTool("rectangle");
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && e.key === "5") {
        setTool("arrow");
      }
    });
    const webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
    setWs(webSocket);
    webSocket.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Connected from client to websocket server.");
    };

    webSocket.onclose = () => {
      console.log("disconnected from client to websocket server.");
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = async (message) => {
      const data = await JSON.parse(message.data);
      // console.log(data);
      if (data.type) setClientId(data.message);
      else if (data.rectangles) {
        setRectangles(data.rectangles);
      } else if (data.circles) {
        setCircles(data.circles);
      } else if (data.lines) {
        setLines(data.lines);
      } else if (data.arrows) {
        setArrows(data.arrows);
      } else if (data.texts) {
        setTexts(data.texts);
      }
      // setRectangles(data.rectangles);
    };

    return () => {
      webSocket.close();
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", () => {});
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center gap-3 relative overflow-hidden"
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Control+Alt+1") {
          setIsDraggable(true);
        }
      }}
    >
      {cliendId ? (
        <div className="text-white absolute right-3 top-3">Id : {cliendId}</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="text-white absolute right-3 top-3">
          Generating Id...
        </div>
      )}
      {tool === "text" ? (
        <input
          type="text"
          className="border-2 blorder-white bg-transparent rounded-md outline-none text-sm px-3 py-2 text-white absolute top-[50%] left-[50%] transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 z-10"
          value={inputText}
          onChange={(e) => setInputText(e.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
              const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
              const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
              setTexts([...texts, { text: inputText, pos: [x, y] }]);
              ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ texts }));
              setInputText("");
              setTool("pen");
            }
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
      <Stage
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMousemove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        className="border-2 border-black bg-[#121212]"
      >
        <Layer>
          {lines.map((line, i) => (
            <Line key={i} points={line} stroke="#d3d3d3" strokeWidth={2} />
          ))}
          {circles.map((circle, i) => (
            <Circle
              key={i}
              {...circle}
              stroke="#d3d3d3"
              draggable={isDraggable}
              onDragEnd={(e) => {
                const x = e.target.x();
                const y = e.target.y();
                setCircles((c) => {
                  const newCircles = c;
                  newCircles[i].x = x;
                  newCircles[i].y = y;
                  return newCircles;
                });
                ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ circles }));
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            />
          ))}
          {texts.map((text, i) => (
            <Text
              key={i}
              text={text.text}
              x={text.pos[0]}
              y={text.pos[1]}
              fill="#d3d3d3"
              draggable={isDraggable}
              onDragEnd={(e) => {
                const x = e.target.x();
                const y = e.target.y();
                setTexts((t) => {
                  const newTexts = t;
                  newTexts[i].pos = [x, y];
                  return newTexts;
                });
                ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ texts }));
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            />
          ))}
          {rectangles.map((rectangle, i) => (
            <Rect
              key={i}
              {...rectangle}
              stroke="#d3d3d3"
              draggable={isDraggable}
              onDragEnd={(e) => {
                const x = e.target.x();
                const y = e.target.y();
                setRectangles((r) => {
                  const newRectangles = r;
                  newRectangles[i].x = x;
                  newRectangles[i].y = y;
                  return newRectangles;
                });
                ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ rectangles }));
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            />
          ))}
          {arrows.map((arrow, i) => (
            <Arrow
              points={arrow.points}
              key={i}
              stroke="#d3d3d3"
              strokeWidth={2}
              // draggable={isDraggable}
              onDragEnd={(e) => {
                const x = e.target.x();
                const y = e.target.y();
                setArrows((a) => {
                  const newArrows = a;
                  newArrows[newArrows.length - 1].points = [
                    a[i].points[0],
                    a[i].points[1],
                    x,
                    y,
                  ];
                  return newArrows;
                });
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
      <div className="bg-[#232329] text-white py-1 px-2 rounded-md absolute top-4">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex gap-2 hover:cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-[#31303b]">
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                isDrawing.current = false;
                setIsDraggable(true);
              }}
            >
              <SquareMousePointer size={16} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-2 hover:cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-[#31303b]">
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setTool("text");
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            >
              <RemoveFormatting size={16} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-2 hover:cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-[#31303b]">
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setTool("pen");
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            >
              <PenLine size={16} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-2 hover:cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-[#31303b]">
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setTool("circle");
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            >
              <IconCircle size={16} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-2 hover:cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-[#31303b]">
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setTool("rectangle");
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            >
              <RectangleHorizontal size={16} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-2 hover:cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-[#31303b]">
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setTool("arrow");
                setIsDraggable(false);
              }}
            >
              <MoveRight size={16} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex absolute left-3 top-3 gap-4">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="border-2 blorder-white bg-transparent rounded-md outline-none text-sm px-3 py-2 text-white"
          value={roomId}
          onChange={(e) => setRoomId(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter Room Id"
        />
        <button
          className="text-white px-3 py-2 border-white border-2 rounded-md"
          onClick={() => {
            ws?.send(JSON.stringify({ roomId }));
          }}
        >
          Join
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Whiteboard;


I am using tailwind css for styling purpose.
And here is my backend file that is websocket handling -
// index.js
import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from server.");
});

const server = app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on 8000.");
});

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });

const clients = [];
let room = [];

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  // console.log(clients);
  const clientId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9);
  clients.push({ ws, clientId });

  clients.forEach((client) => {
    if (client.ws === ws) {
      client.ws.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          message: client.clientId,
          type: "id",
        }),
        { binary: false }
      );
    }
  });

  ws.on("message", async (message) => {
    const data = await JSON.parse(message);

    if (data.roomId) {
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        if (client.ws === ws) {
          room.push(client.clientId);
          room.push(data.roomId);
        }
      });
    } else if (room.includes(clientId)) {
      // console.log(room);
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        room.forEach((r) => {
          if (client.clientId === r && client.ws !== ws) {
            client.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data), { binary: false });
          }
        });
      });
    }
    // console.log(room);
    // console.log(data);
    // clients.forEach((client) => {
    //   if (client.ws !== ws) {
    //     client.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data), { binary: false });
    //   }
    // });
  });

  ws.on("close", () => {
    // console.log("Connection closed.");
    room = [];
  });
  // ws.send("You are connected. Your id : " + );
});


The logic I have written is, the data will be shared between the two clients who are in the room array, otherwise no data will be send to the frontend.
The clients disconnect as soon as I go to the localhost:3000 not when I start drawing.
Any help would be appreciated, and also can anyone suggest how I can modify it to accomodate multiple clients and share data between them?
Thank You.
Here is an image of the final website.](https://i.sstatic.net/1DNT1.png)
